# Atribute sample texture, where to find the keyframes animated on the texture properties

Tags: texture-coordinates, geometry-nodes

I'm using atribute sample texture and trying to animate the points by keyframing the size and brightness of a clouds texture. I managed to insert keyframes and I can see it's animating, but then if I want to edit keyframes, the F curves or even bake it to sound, I can't find them on the timeline.

As you can see by the picture, I've got the object and node selected, and yet can't see them.

[image]
[image]

Comment: See that arrow in dope sheet on the upper bar on right? I think it's only showing keyframes for selected objects. Turn that off and you should see it.

Comment: @CobyRandal Yep I've tried all that before posting the question. Still don't know where to find it . I found a workaround. By keyframing the Distance Max value, I can control  it in the graphics editor and it kinda gives me the look I was looking for. It still would be cool to find them keyframes from the texture panel , for future reference. Thanks though Coby. Appreciate it.

Comment: Also noticed that, when using other modifiers, other than Geometry Nodes, when inserting keyframes on the texture tab parameters, the  keyframes are now added to the timeline. Can this be a Geometry Nodes thing/bug or its me just missing it.